# Condensation and potential mold on inside of arch window

Tags: windows, condensation, window-frame

It's a single pane window and the condensation is on the inside of the window. Also, should I cut out what appears to be mold on the wood trim?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: You only cut out rotten wood.  Mold is cleaned off with bleach or any other mold killer/remover.

Comment: One of those window insulation kits might help with the condensation.  Will help preventing warm moist house air hitting the cold window.

Comment: Is that single-pane glazing?

Comment: You say "also should I..." what's the other question? That seems to be the only one you've asked and it really has nothing to do with windows.